# Compare values with a list of values in np.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I want to transform RGB labels of a mask of PASCAL to integer labels, how can I do that using numpy? I searched for a long time, but I cannot find a fast way to do it.

Say, I have a ( W = 3, H = 3, C=3) image, the value in each pixel is a RGB label, say `[128, 0, 128]` means this label belongs to Class 1, and `[128, 256, 0]` means this is labeled as Class 2, and `[1, 1, 1]` means this is labeled as Class 3. For example, in this image, pixels are labeled as `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]` conceptually and encoded physically by such RGB label convention. And I want to exactly convert this ( W = 3, H = 3, C=3) mask to a ( W = 3, H = 3, C=1) mask, which in this case is exactly `[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]]`.

For clearity, the input is `[[[128, 0, 128],[128, 0, 128],[128, 0, 128]],[[128, 256, 0],[128, 256, 0],[128, 256, 0]], [[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]]`, which is (3,3,3), and the output should be `[[[1],[1],[1]],[[2],[2],[2]],[[3],[3],[3]]]`, which is (3,3,1)

Such conversion means we need to pick the vector of each pixel and compare it with a list of encoding of length 3 in this example and get the index of a match.
How can I do that in a fast way using numpy?

A very trivial and very slow implementation will be

```
labels = np.array([[128, 0, 128], [128, 256, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
def convert(x):
    a = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1), x.dtype)
    a = a-1 # defaut label is -1
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            # for each pixel, compare its color vector with those in `labels`, and find out the idx of matched one
            for idx, l in enumerate(labels):
                if np.array_equal(x[i][j], l):
                    a[i][j] = idx+1
    return a
```

Comment: Have you tried `np.argmax(image, axis=0)`?

Comment: It seems to me `np.argmax` cannot solve this problem, can you show how to do this?

Comment: Ok, your question seems to be missing an image, could you update that? And to be clear, basically you want to label each pixel with the highest of rgb value right(i mean 1 for R, 2 for G ....?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the example is misleading in some way. It's not about the value, but the encoding convention. I'll change the example a bit

Comment: I can't get to understand the question. Please provide exact input and exact output.

Comment: OK, now the trivial implementation exactly matches the problem description, and input and output are added

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np


inp = [
    [
        [128, 0, 128],
        [128, 0, 128],
        [128, 0, 128]
    ],
    [
        [128, 256, 0],
        [128, 256, 0],
        [128, 256, 0]
    ],
    [
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]
    ]
]
out_expected = [[[1],[1],[1]],[[2],[2],[2]],[[3],[3],[3]]]

inp_np = np.array(inp)
out_np_expected = np.array(out_expected)

label1 = np.array([128, 0, 128])
label2 = np.array([128, 256, 0])
label3 = np.array([1, 1, 1])

label1_mask = np.equal(inp_np, label1)
label2_mask = np.equal(inp_np, label2)
label3_mask = np.equal(inp_np, label3)

out_np = np.zeros((inp_np.shape[0], inp_np.shape[1]))
label1_reduced = np.all(label1_mask, axis=2)
label2_reduced = np.all(label2_mask, axis=2)
label3_reduced = np.all(label3_mask, axis=2)

out_np[label1_reduced] = 1
out_np[label2_reduced] = 2
out_np[label3_reduced] = 3
out_np = out_np[..., np.newaxis]

np.testing.assert_equal(out_np, out_np_expected)
```

1. Check input equality against the template, per coordinate (using `np.equal`)
2. Force equality over the entire template using `np.all`
3. Assign desired labels (which seem to be arbitrary numbers)
4. Add an axis to the result, as required in the question
5. Verify using `np.testing.assert_equal`

Comment: Thanks! I think the idea is basically the same as that of @Poe Dator

Comment: Looks likehe beat me by a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

@macguffin,
I suggest to combine `==`, `np.all()`, `np.sum()`:

```
labels = np.array([[128, 0, 128], [128, 256, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
inputs = np.array([[[128, 0, 128],[128, 0, 128],[128, 0, 128]],
    [[128, 256, 0],[128, 256, 0],[128, 256, 0]], 
    [[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]])

result = np.sum(
    [np.expand_dims(
        np.all(inputs == labels[i], axis=-1), axis=-1) * (i+1) \
        for i in range (labels.shape[0])],
    axis = 1)


array([[[1], [1], [1]],    
       [[2], [2], [2]],    
       [[3], [3], [3]]])
```

Comment: I think there's a typo, in which `np.all(inputs == labels[0], axis=-1)` should be `np.all(inputs == labels[i], axis=-1)` if I get it right

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different take towards the solution, one liner-

```py
image = np.array([[[128, 0, 128],[128, 0, 128],[128, 0, 128]],  # channels are along axis 2
                  [[128, 256, 0],[128, 256, 0],[128, 256, 0]], 
                  [[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]])

# since first label has minimum at 1st index
# since second label has a minimum at 2nd index
# since third label has a minimum at 0th index, since all are equal

labels = np.argmin(image, axis=2)

# output is
# array([[1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 2],
#        [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)

# if the 3rd label should definitely be 3
labels[labels == 0] = 3

# output is
# array([[1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 2],
#        [3, 3, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: If the labels or the image change this will fail...

Comment: I agree, this is only good as long as the assumptions are valid

Comment: Yes, it's hack, though. Sadly, the labels of PASCAL VOC will not have such coincidence.

Comment: Just look out for utilizing the **order** in the data with which you are working. The labels in this cases seemed oddly specific and hence the idea.